# Passing returned jquery var to another jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

What is the best way to get the following returned var (in jQuery):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var theFormID = jQuery(parent.document).find('.theformclass').find('input[name="form_id"]').val();
});
```

the above code is ok as it returnes the value i need - so the question is how do i "paste" (print) it in the script that comes after it (where it says: 
HERE-IS-WHERE-I-NEED-THE-RETURNED-VALUE)

```
jQuery(parent.document).find('#abc_HERE-IS-WHERE-I-NEED-THE-RETURNED-VALUE_number_103').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

thanks for your help :)

https://jsfiddle.net/jhk926ya/

EDIT: thanks to @brian and @showdev - both solutions were correct, problem on my side was jquery sizzle.

works perfectly :) thank you again guys

Comment: You want to use the value of `theFormID` as the string selector for `find()`?

Comment: @showdev i want to use the value of 'theFormID' where it says "HERE-IS-WHERE-I-NEED-THE-RETURNED-VALUE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I cleaned up my answer a little bit, should be a bit more readable. You just need to break up your string and concatenate it with the returned value.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $parent = jQuery(parent.document); // cache this so jquery doesnt have to instantiate the same object twice

    var theFormID = $parent
        .find('.theformclass')
        .find('input[name="form_id"]').val();

    var $form = $parent
        .find("#abc_" + theFormId + "_number_103")
        .fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

Comment: did you see that the place where i need the value of theformID var is in the middle of the selector (between #abc_ to  _number_103)?

#abc_HERE-IS-WHERE-I-NEED-THE-RETURNED-VALUE_number_103'

Comment: @user3368504 updated my answer. You just need to concatenate the string with the value in the middle.

Comment: thnks, but this is the result i got:

<code>
var $form = $parent
        .find("#formclass_" + theFormId + "_number_103")
        .fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
</code>

basicly, it just printed the code as is - without replacing the + theformID + with the needed value...

Comment: Whats the value returned to `theFormId`? What's the value of `input[name="form_id"]`?

Comment: each time page loads it changes - but its a number.

this number represents the id of the form... by knowing it im trying to target it with second code.

i do get the form id number alright, problem is with "pasting" it where i need in second code :(

Comment: Oh. Change `theFormId` to `theFormId.toString()`. It shouldn't matter though since javascript should automatically parse it as a string when adding it to another string. I'm also fairly certain `.val()` will return a string as well.

Comment: :( it just prints it as is

Comment: I can't help you if you cant show me an example of what I asked for (values of `theFormdId` and `input[name="form_id"]`. It doesn't matter if they change every time.

Comment: You didn't even attempt to use my solution and it's filled with invalid HTML and jquery wasn't included. I fixed it. jsfiddle automatically wraps your code in `$(document).ready()` - https://jsfiddle.net/jhk926ya/4/

Comment: i sure did try - but didnt get results as you... i can see it works on your jsfiddle but for some reason, it doesnt work on my end.

 this is what i get in console: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #abc__' + theFormID + '_number_103

Answer (score 0):

You can include the value of `theFormID` when building your string selector by using concatenation.
In JavaScript, string concatenation can be done with "[+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition)".

I also simplified the code by removing some seemingly unnecessary calls to `find()`.

```js
// determine the value of the <input>
var theFormID = jQuery('.theformclass input[name=form_id]').val();

// concatenate the value of the <input> into your selector
jQuery('#abc_' + theFormID + '_number_103').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

```css
#abc_another_number_103 { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="theformclass">
  <input name="form_id" value="another" />
</div>

<div id="abc_another_number_103">test</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this wont get me the result i need...

the place where i need the value of theformID var inserted is in the middle of the selector (between #abc_ to _number_103) of the script that comes after the first one...

Comment: Please see my edit. In my example, the value of `theFormID` is being concatenated with your other strings to build a complete selector (e.g. #abc_VALUE_number_103).

Comment: thanks, but i dont have access to the form itself...

i mean - form divs are already generated (each time diffrent id's) and im trying to add some onclick functions to them...

problem is that i do get the correct value with first code BUT i cant get the value "pasted" where it ineeds in the second code...

Comment: If you're having trouble, I suggest [editing your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37684357/edit) to include a working example of your code. Try to show us exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm confused. It doesn't seem that you tried my suggestions. https://jsfiddle.net/jhk926ya/5/

Comment: i sure did try - but didnt get as lucky as you... i can see it works on jsfiddle - for some reason, it doesnt work on my end.

this is what i get in console:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #abc__' + theFormID + '_number_103